# How to create a view out of a SQL-Statement received from a function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I'm currently working with Oracle Apex and the Oracle Database. 
I've created a function which is building a SQL-Query dynamically and returns it afterwards. It is neccessary to do this in a function because the pivot-function from oracle don't allow dynamic content in the IN() section. 
Because of the given circumstances my plan was to create a View which fetches the Query from the function and execute it.

Can anybody give me a hint how to create this view without PL-/SQL?

I hope you can follow my thoughts without concrete Code in here.

Thanks!

Kai

Comment: As your sql is dynamic, it seems that it depends on some parameters and can be different on each invocation. So, how you can create a view based on that function? Do you want to create a new view on each invocation of the function?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! There isn't any parameter but int this function there is a subquery which is fetching an up to date list of values (aggregated).

Comment: Can you add the code of your function? Does your subquery returns the list of columns you need to be shown in your view?

Comment: sadly i can't add the code because it would not make much sense without the sensible data. I try to make it more transparent: I'm using multiple variables which contains different parts of the query. The dynamic data which is fetched by a subquery will be placed in the final variable (and concatinated). The function is returning the whole SQL-Query in one String.

Comment: Well, as I understand your function returns some SELECT statement string and you want a view to be created based on this query. But this SELECT statement can be different on each invocation of this function. Do you want the view to be recreated if it happens?

Comment: Yes this is right. The function returns a SELECT-Statement which can be different. This could be 5 minutes or 2 weeks or more. It would be perfect if the View would execute this function on each invocation.

Comment: Well, a view can not execute a function in the way you wish. I understand that you want to have some kind of dynamic view, but it is not possible. A view is created with some SELECT statement and you can not change it on view invocation. You should recreate the view to be able to change its SELECT. What is possible to do is to create a function which will create/recreate the view based on your function returning the SQL.

Comment: Okay, i think i have to find another way then. Thank you for your patience and help!